# mysql two table, 3 column dependent query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I need to be able to do is get a list of all 'date' that correspond to a 'starName'.  What I have joined the two tables, but I can't figure out how to then search the joined tables for 'starName'.

Here is the query I have so far:

```sql
SELECT date,
       COUNT(*) 
  FROM Scans, 
       Targets 
 WHERE Scans.idTarget = Targets.id 
 GROUP BY date;
```

Here are my tables:

```
    Targets
    | id | starName | more columns.... |
    -----------------
    | 1  | WHITE    |
    | 2  | IOT CAS  |
    | 3  | 21 ALP   |

    Scans
    | date | idTarget | more columns.... |
    -------------------
    | 1-1  | 1        |
    | 3-6  | 3        |
    | 11-1 | 2        |
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are looking for a particular starName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT date,COUNT(*) 
FROM Scans, Targets 
WHERE Scans.idTarget = Targets.id 
AND targets.starName like '%21%'  --This is the line you need or something like it
GROUP BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
    s.date
FROM 
    Scans AS s, Targets AS t
WHERE
    s.idTarget = t.id AND
    t.starName = 'WHITE'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add it to your `WHERE` clause.

So you'll have something like:

```
    WHERE
        Scans.idTarget = Targets.id
        AND Targets.startName = <whatever>
```